# Assembly analyze C system() function

Tags: ollydbg, assembly, c

So I made a very simple C program to study how C works on the inside. It has just 1 line in the main() excluding return 0:

```
system("cls");
```

If I use ollydebugger to analyze this program It will show something like this(text after the semicolons are comments generated by ollydebugger.

```
MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],test_1.004030EC     ; ||ASCII "cls"
CALL <JMP.&msvcrt.system>                ; |\system
```

Can someone explain what this means, and if I want to change the "cls" called in the system() to another command, where is the "cls" stored? And how do I modify it?

Comment: Ascii string `cls` is stored at virtual address `004030EC`. In Olly press ,Ctrl + G to go there.

Answer (score 1):

The Ascii string `cls` is stored at address `0x004030EC`. Why is it stored at that location is probably compiler related.

The `ESP` register holds the address of the top of the stack. What your instruction

```
MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],test_1.004030EC     ; ||ASCII "cls"
```

means is to put the value `0x004030EC` to the address pointed to by `ESP`. If the value of `ESP` is, lets say, `ESP = 0x0018FF8C`, then the value at address `0x0018FF8C` will be `0x004030EC` after the above `MOV` instruction is executed.

If you want to change the string `cls` to something else, you can position at the dump window in Olly and press CTRL-G. A popup box will appear and there you will enter `0x004030EC` and press `Ok`. After that right click on the first byte at that address, which should be `0x63` (the letter 'c' from string "cls") and choose `Binary -> Edit`. There you can enter your new string that will be passed to the `CALL` instruction.